# How to get number of users logged last 3 month using Jquery and JSON API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I would like to get the number of users who logged last 3 months using JSON API and Jquery.

So far this is what I have done.

```
$.getJSON('users.json', function(data) {

        var numberOfUserLogged = 0;
       var d1 = new Date();
       var d2 = new Date(d1.setMonth(d1.getMonth-3));

        $.each(data, function(key, value)
        {

            numberOfUserLogged +=1;

            if(d1==d2)
            {
                $(".result").html("numberOfUserLogged ==>" + numberOfUserLogged);
            }

        });
});
```

JSON SAMPLE API :

```
[{"id":987,"username":"jstephensre","active":false,"password":"8de90ec658d72b54ef0b270611ef9eb6241fa59b77b5c98b9bffb4fd631a4b10","first_name":"Johnny","last_name":"Stephens","last_login":"6/7/2016","email":"jstephensre@opensource.org","avatar":"https://robohash.org/nihilpariaturrepudiandae.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":[],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"117187617-3","color":"#6adf06","drugs":["Zicam Cold Remedy Ultra Rapidmelts","BUTALBITAL, ACETAMINOPHEN AND CAFFEINE"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"8.65972","lng":"-75.12809"}},
{"id":988,"username":"dtorresrf","active":true,"password":"443f2261332613a2da952d05a25ceec2d8eb9ed177ce830b3b4d6fbbe536e2c0","first_name":null,"last_name":"Torres","last_login":null,"email":"atorresrf@facebook.com","avatar":"https://robohash.org/idnihilut.bmp?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Female","Female"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":null,"color":"#a04fce","drugs":["Cockroach, American","Lisinopril and Hydrochlorothiazide"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"9.86667","lng":"6.71667"}},
{"id":989,"username":"jsmithrg","active":false,"password":"4e9750746ad03f82717ebd702c03c92749de1cbc820798ab409fb5e6760101ad","first_name":null,"last_name":"Smith","last_login":null,"email":"tsmithrg@creativecommons.org","avatar":null,"gender":["Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":null,"color":"#3bff1e","drugs":["Yellow Pine","Meprobamate","GenRx Daily Defense Antifungal"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"-16.00528","lng":"-41.29722"}},
{"id":990,"username":"sroserh","active":false,"password":"ab83a77062c8ee868f3b966d50a8ee39f63e3cec81349b83b81adcd3c6fa5da3","first_name":"Sarah","last_name":null,"last_login":"12/19/2015","email":"sromerorh@about.me","avatar":null,"gender":[],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"117541910-9","color":"#ac8603","drugs":["MORUS ALBA POLLEN","enema","Altipres-B"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"32.26616","lng":"35.00893"}},
{"id":991,"username":"sholmesri","active":false,"password":"11802fc53531079cdf8033e6772ffc5ac47c8ea8a453b66e8ac8df9ae29d9543","first_name":"Susan","last_name":"Holmes","last_login":"1/28/2016","email":"sholmesri@mozilla.com","avatar":"https://robohash.org/doloreshicqui.png?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Male","Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"658583882-3","color":"#04da21","drugs":["Tempra","Estradiol Transdermal System"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"-39.23686","lng":"-70.9197"}},
{"id":992,"username":"rhayesrj","active":true,"password":"beae358b1eb873bac4fa640410520157f26738ee4d2de1144f30101c6af8e259","first_name":"Rachel","last_name":"Hayes","last_login":"12/7/2015","email":null,"avatar":"https://robohash.org/teneturautest.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"291847889-X","color":null,"drugs":["BUDESONIDE","Doxorubicin Hydrochloride","Hydrocodone Bitartrate and Acetaminophen"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"-20.58333","lng":"48.53333"}},
{"id":993,"username":"jcampbellrk","active":false,"password":"9602ccbe7599aefea9a25eb05ab2ede44302f57fd153bad07aa0f5a2f46be537","first_name":"Joan","last_name":"Campbell","last_login":"8/29/2016","email":"jcampbellrk@bravesites.com","avatar":"https://robohash.org/numquamutquae.png?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"588841638-X","color":"#7c5963","drugs":[]},"coordinates":{"lat":"57.6531","lng":"14.6968"}},
{"id":994,"username":"ejamesrl","active":false,"password":"55b1d2418621cda82225bf569f5f30c5b5fcfe5ae7aef6b1e3418a97335b47ab","first_name":"Elizabeth","last_name":"James","last_login":"1/14/2016","email":"ejamesrl@geocities.jp","avatar":null,"gender":["Female"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"026417147-0","color":"#ba1d5c","drugs":["Losartan Potassium and Hydrochlorothiazide","Ramipril"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"54.64043","lng":"32.87811"}},
{"id":995,"username":"krogersrm","active":true,"password":"c5a8921245a345fb133193f8ceb14021469b4f42a7d945e835b9497081fb7130","first_name":"Kathleen","last_name":null,"last_login":"6/13/2016","email":"khansenrm@nationalgeographic.com","avatar":"https://robohash.org/mollitiasuscipitmagnam.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"636138809-3","color":"#1c858e","drugs":["Tramadol Hydrochloride","iBlanc Restora-Bright"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"12.71402","lng":"121.51242"}},
{"id":996,"username":"sperkinsrn","active":false,"password":"c0f48289a4145ffd34374f7236ea4e650df57cff11f4f77b865a44dde410cfb8","first_name":"Sarah","last_name":"Perkins","last_login":"8/31/2016","email":null,"avatar":"https://robohash.org/consequaturculpavelit.png?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Male","Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"561211079-0","color":null,"drugs":["Caduet"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"43.30472","lng":"124.32778"}},
{"id":997,"username":"jlanero","active":false,"password":"0430117ff30143b0f3727527f62346351582a396cc60a5bf599e674cc34c07c5","first_name":"Jack","last_name":"Lane","last_login":"3/20/2016","email":null,"avatar":null,"gender":[],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"819102101-3","color":null,"drugs":["RIFAMPIN"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"51.8796","lng":"4.5059"}},
{"id":998,"username":"wroserp","active":true,"password":"626e6d1a1a92ff6e741ae21e3bbbae265000ca0f87306590c2344d4130dd57a9","first_name":"Willie","last_name":"Rose","last_login":"10/16/2016","email":null,"avatar":null,"gender":["Male"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"108540866-3","color":null,"drugs":["OXYGEN","Garnier Fructis Antidandruff"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"57.58167","lng":"83.76917"}},
{"id":999,"username":"sphillipsrq","active":false,"password":"de0a87749bb04b2630ac6dbeb7259947383189afb6c2b458d80a15f6881b0439","first_name":"Stephanie","last_name":"Phillips","last_login":"11/24/2016","email":"sphillipsrq@wikia.com","avatar":"https://robohash.org/laborerepellendustemporibus.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":[],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"721916787-3","color":"#9eee74","drugs":[]},"coordinates":{"lat":"51.0016","lng":"21.71474"}},
{"id":1000,"username":"phicksrr","active":false,"password":"2a27d007956e55da298aa3fb427a5a8ed7a8d661f4d4a2e340a98026996521eb","first_name":"Phyllis","last_name":"Hicks","last_login":"2/14/2016","email":null,"avatar":"https://robohash.org/sedsednon.bmp?size=50x50&set=set1","gender":["Female","Female"],"favorites":{"book-isbn":"268196481-4","color":null,"drugs":["Ibuprofen"]},"coordinates":{"lat":"-6.22625","lng":"106.0253"}}];
```

Nothing displays in my HTML, what is wrong with my code? any help will be helpful

Comment: Try moving the code where you set the html outside the scope of the `each` block.

Comment: can you please show it in jsfiddle if you dont mind? am a newbie though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var data = [{ "id": 987, "username": "jstephensre", "active": false, "password": "8de90ec658d72b54ef0b270611ef9eb6241fa59b77b5c98b9bffb4fd631a4b10", "first_name": "Johnny", "last_name": "Stephens", "last_login": "3/7/2017", "email": "jstephensre@opensource.org", "avatar": "https://robohash.org/nihilpariaturrepudiandae.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1", "gender": [], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "117187617-3", "color": "#6adf06", "drugs": ["Zicam Cold Remedy Ultra Rapidmelts", "BUTALBITAL, ACETAMINOPHEN AND CAFFEINE"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "8.65972", "lng": "-75.12809" } },
{ "id": 988, "username": "dtorresrf", "active": true, "password": "443f2261332613a2da952d05a25ceec2d8eb9ed177ce830b3b4d6fbbe536e2c0", "first_name": null, "last_name": "Torres", "last_login": null, "email": "atorresrf@facebook.com", "avatar": "https://robohash.org/idnihilut.bmp?size=50x50&set=set1", "gender": ["Female", "Female"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": null, "color": "#a04fce", "drugs": ["Cockroach, American", "Lisinopril and Hydrochlorothiazide"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "9.86667", "lng": "6.71667" } },
{ "id": 989, "username": "jsmithrg", "active": false, "password": "4e9750746ad03f82717ebd702c03c92749de1cbc820798ab409fb5e6760101ad", "first_name": null, "last_name": "Smith", "last_login": null, "email": "tsmithrg@creativecommons.org", "avatar": null, "gender": ["Male"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": null, "color": "#3bff1e", "drugs": ["Yellow Pine", "Meprobamate", "GenRx Daily Defense Antifungal"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "-16.00528", "lng": "-41.29722" } },
{ "id": 990, "username": "sroserh", "active": false, "password": "ab83a77062c8ee868f3b966d50a8ee39f63e3cec81349b83b81adcd3c6fa5da3", "first_name": "Sarah", "last_name": null, "last_login": "3/19/2015", "email": "sromerorh@about.me", "avatar": null, "gender": [], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "117541910-9", "color": "#ac8603", "drugs": ["MORUS ALBA POLLEN", "enema", "Altipres-B"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "32.26616", "lng": "35.00893" } },
{ "id": 991, "username": "sholmesri", "active": false, "password": "11802fc53531079cdf8033e6772ffc5ac47c8ea8a453b66e8ac8df9ae29d9543", "first_name": "Susan", "last_name": "Holmes", "last_login": "1/28/2017", "email": "sholmesri@mozilla.com", "avatar": "https://robohash.org/doloreshicqui.png?size=50x50&set=set1", "gender": ["Male", "Male"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "658583882-3", "color": "#04da21", "drugs": ["Tempra", "Estradiol Transdermal System"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "-39.23686", "lng": "-70.9197" } },
{ "id": 992, "username": "rhayesrj", "active": true, "password": "beae358b1eb873bac4fa640410520157f26738ee4d2de1144f30101c6af8e259", "first_name": "Rachel", "last_name": "Hayes", "last_login": "3/7/2015", "email": null, "avatar": "https://robohash.org/teneturautest.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1", "gender": ["Male"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "291847889-X", "color": null, "drugs": ["BUDESONIDE", "Doxorubicin Hydrochloride", "Hydrocodone Bitartrate and Acetaminophen"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "-20.58333", "lng": "48.53333" } },
{ "id": 993, "username": "jcampbellrk", "active": false, "password": "9602ccbe7599aefea9a25eb05ab2ede44302f57fd153bad07aa0f5a2f46be537", "first_name": "Joan", "last_name": "Campbell", "last_login": "8/29/2017", "email": "jcampbellrk@bravesites.com", "avatar": "https://robohash.org/numquamutquae.png?size=50x50&set=set1", "gender": ["Male"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "588841638-X", "color": "#7c5963", "drugs": [] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "57.6531", "lng": "14.6968" } },
{ "id": 994, "username": "ejamesrl", "active": false, "password": "55b1d2418621cda82225bf569f5f30c5b5fcfe5ae7aef6b1e3418a97335b47ab", "first_name": "Elizabeth", "last_name": "James", "last_login": "1/14/2017", "email": "ejamesrl@geocities.jp", "avatar": null, "gender": ["Female"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "026417147-0", "color": "#ba1d5c", "drugs": ["Losartan Potassium and Hydrochlorothiazide", "Ramipril"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "54.64043", "lng": "32.87811" } },
{ "id": 995, "username": "krogersrm", "active": true, "password": "c5a8921245a345fb133193f8ceb14021469b4f42a7d945e835b9497081fb7130", "first_name": "Kathleen", "last_name": null, "last_login": "6/13/2017", "email": "khansenrm@nationalgeographic.com", "avatar": "https://robohash.org/mollitiasuscipitmagnam.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1", "gender": ["Male"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "636138809-3", "color": "#1c858e", "drugs": ["Tramadol Hydrochloride", "iBlanc Restora-Bright"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "12.71402", "lng": "121.51242" } },
{ "id": 996, "username": "sperkinsrn", "active": false, "password": "c0f48289a4145ffd34374f7236ea4e650df57cff11f4f77b865a44dde410cfb8", "first_name": "Sarah", "last_name": "Perkins", "last_login": "8/31/2017", "email": null, "avatar": "https://robohash.org/consequaturculpavelit.png?size=50x50&set=set1", "gender": ["Male", "Male"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "561211079-0", "color": null, "drugs": ["Caduet"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "43.30472", "lng": "124.32778" } },
{ "id": 997, "username": "jlanero", "active": false, "password": "0430117ff30143b0f3727527f62346351582a396cc60a5bf599e674cc34c07c5", "first_name": "Jack", "last_name": "Lane", "last_login": "3/20/2017", "email": null, "avatar": null, "gender": [], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "819102101-3", "color": null, "drugs": ["RIFAMPIN"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "51.8796", "lng": "4.5059" } },
{ "id": 998, "username": "wroserp", "active": true, "password": "626e6d1a1a92ff6e741ae21e3bbbae265000ca0f87306590c2344d4130dd57a9", "first_name": "Willie", "last_name": "Rose", "last_login": "10/16/2017", "email": null, "avatar": null, "gender": ["Male"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "108540866-3", "color": null, "drugs": ["OXYGEN", "Garnier Fructis Antidandruff"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "57.58167", "lng": "83.76917" } },
{ "id": 999, "username": "sphillipsrq", "active": false, "password": "de0a87749bb04b2630ac6dbeb7259947383189afb6c2b458d80a15f6881b0439", "first_name": "Stephanie", "last_name": "Phillips", "last_login": "11/24/2017", "email": "sphillipsrq@wikia.com", "avatar": "https://robohash.org/laborerepellendustemporibus.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1", "gender": [], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "721916787-3", "color": "#9eee74", "drugs": [] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "51.0016", "lng": "21.71474" } },
{ "id": 1000, "username": "phicksrr", "active": false, "password": "2a27d007956e55da298aa3fb427a5a8ed7a8d661f4d4a2e340a98026996521eb", "first_name": "Phyllis", "last_name": "Hicks", "last_login": "2/14/2017", "email": null, "avatar": "https://robohash.org/sedsednon.bmp?size=50x50&set=set1", "gender": ["Female", "Female"], "favorites": { "book-isbn": "268196481-4", "color": null, "drugs": ["Ibuprofen"] }, "coordinates": { "lat": "-6.22625", "lng": "106.0253" } }];


$(function () {
    var d = data.filter(filterByID)    
    var html = '';
    
    $.each(d, function(){ 
       html += 
      '<div>'+this.id+'<div>'+
      '<div>'+this.username+'<div>'+
      '<div>'+this.first_name+'<div>';
    });
    
    $('#total').text(d.length+" No. of records found!");
    $('div').append(html);    
});


function filterByID(item) {

    var d1 = new Date();
    var d2 = new Date(item.last_login);
    if ((d1.getMonth() - 3) == d2.getMonth() + 1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="data"><div>
<label id="total"><label>
```

you need to find records by the last login date like above method.

Comment: Hii  I tried your method but in my html it displays [object].[object] etc

Comment: if you want to put in HTML then you need to use each and find their object value.

Comment: can you please show it in jsfiddle if you dont mind am a newbie in Javascript, ?

Comment: Updated answer you can check

Comment: Up Vote me Please.

Comment: so if I want to display a total number of users instead of names what should I do?

Comment: Updated bro check again